# Php function to return only the date from a DateTime format

Tags: php, datetime

I have a string with the DateTime format `'2022-03-17T15:00:00+02:00'` and I need a php function to return only the Date `'2022-03-17'`. I didn't find a solution. The string `'2022-03-17T15:00:00+02:00'` is variable in the xml feed. It change every day, so it must formatted to included in the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
store your date time in a variable and try this:

$date_to_be_formatted = '2022-03-17T15:00:00+02:00';
echo get_date($date_to_be_formatted);

function get_date($date_to_be_formatted){
    $formatted_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date_to_be_formatted));
    return $formatted_date;
  }
    
    output:
    2022-03-17
```

Comment: Where is `$date` coming from?

Answer (score 0):

strtotime is not suitable in conjunction with date to convert a date that contains a time zone such as +02:00 here. Errors may occur in connection with other time zones. Example:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

$time = '2022-03-17T01:00:00+02:00';
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime($time)); 
//2022-03-16
```

[See for yourself](https://3v4l.org/GJRjh)!

The use of DateTime is generally recommended here, since the time zones are handled correctly.

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

$time = '2022-03-17T01:00:00+02:00';
echo date_create($time)->format('Y-m-d'); 
//2022-03-17
```

Comment: That's right. At this point i have to say that i forgot to say that the string `2022-03-17T01:00:00+02:00` is variable in my xml data. How to convert generic like `d-m-yTh:m:s+gmt`. I tried this but it returned error.

Comment: Please edit your question if you want to add important information so all users can see it and include it in their answer.

Comment: It returned 1970-01-01

Comment: question edited.

Answer (score -2):

```
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime($time));
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score -2):

@Denis and @Relcode

That function now working properly:

```
function get_date( $time ) {
$time = '2022-03-17T15:00:00+02:00';
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime($time)); 
}

echo get_date('2022-03-17T15:00:00+02:00');
```

Output: 2022-03-17

Comment: You cannot `echo` the return of `get_date()` because this function doesn't return anything.

Comment: I'm doing to output on tehplayground

Comment: Two `echo`s? Why overwrite `$time` inside your function?

Comment: @brombeer I'm confused, i can't understand the right function to apply in my function.php file.